# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference [Database Sqlite]

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am trying  to open the database and retrieve the data and display the data as cardview in RecyclerView. I dont know much about context. I am getting the error in context. also hoe to use getActivity() most answers talked about it.

```
public class getList extends Activity{

public SQLiteDatabase db;
public List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();

public getList(){
    //REQUIRED PUBLIC CONST
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


public List<String> getListofevents() {

    this.db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("events", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Cursor crs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM event", null);

    while(crs.moveToNext()){
        String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("name"));
        Log.e("The string is : ",uname);
        array.add(uname);
    }
    db.close();
    return array;
}


public List<String> getListofstatus() {
    this.db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("events", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor crs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM event", null);

    while(crs.moveToNext()){
        String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("status"));
        Log.e("The string is : ",uname);
        array1.add(uname);
    }
    db.close();
    return array1;
}
```

}

"events" is the database and "event" is a table.
This is used to create adapter ContactAdapter

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {

public List<String> arrayevent= new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> arraystatus= new ArrayList<String>();
public getList tmp;


public ContactAdapter() {

    tmp = new getList();
    arrayevent = tmp.getListofevents();
    arraystatus = tmp.getListofstatus();
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayevent.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {
    String ce = arrayevent.get(i);
    contactViewHolder.eventName.setText(ce);
    String cs = arraystatus.get(i);
    contactViewHolder.eventName.setText(cs);

}

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);

    return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
}

public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView eventName;
    protected TextView estatus;

    public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        eventName =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
        estatus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eventStatus);
    }
}
```

}

When i am running for first time the app crashes and gives following null exception error.

```
04-02 03:10:59.308 32071-32071/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.mukul.workingtabs, PID: 32071
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory)' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.example.mukul.workingtabs.getList.getListofevents(getList.java:38)
                                                   at com.example.mukul.workingtabs.ContactAdapter.<init>(ContactAdapter.java:22)
                                                   at com.example.mukul.workingtabs.OneFragment.onCreateView(OneFragment.java:38)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:664)
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:731)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                at java.lang.reflect.Meth
```

Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: You shouldn't create your `getList` Activity by calling `new getList()`, you should be doing it by using an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate your Activity in the constructor of the adapter like this:

`public ContactAdapter() {
    tmp = new getList();
    arrayevent = tmp.getListofevents();
    arraystatus = tmp.getListofstatus();
}`

Allow Android to create your Activities and do something like this:

`public ContactAdapter(getList activity) {
    tmp = activity;
    arrayevent = tmp.getListofevents();
    arraystatus = tmp.getListofstatus();
}`

You are getting the error because when you call `openOrCreateDatabase` on your `Activity` the backing `Context` is null because of the way you created the activity as stated above.